# Swift: Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already

Tags: swift, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, presentation, representation

I have 3 controllers like that: A -> B -> C
A: Present to B
B: Present to C

From C, I used the code below to transition to A

```
window.rootViewController = nil
window.rootViewController = vc
let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
let duration: TimeInterval = 0.3
UIView.transition(with: window, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: { _ in
                })
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But a few errors occurred

```
1. [Presentation] Presenting view controller <UIAlertController: 0x146902400> from detached view controller <B> is discouraged.
2. [Assert] Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already.(<_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController: 0x14503bc60>)
3. [Assert] self._currentTransitionDidComplete is nil! for self: <_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController: 0x15b287470>; presentedViewController: <UIAlertController: 0x156ba8e00>; presentingViewController: <UINavigationController: 0x15522a200>
```

Basically it has moved to the correct screen from C to A, but I can't click on any item on the screen.

Please give me suggestions, thank you

Comment: What is `vc`? Is that controller A, B, or C? Why are you setting the root view controller to nil first? That can't be good. Your error message redactions make it very difficult to know what is what. Maybe at least replace `<xxx>` with `<A>` or `<C>`, etc.

Comment: @HangarRash I updated my question. Setting the root view controller to nil first because I have the root view controller when I declare vc like that: `let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)`